# is there any tool to generate XML configuration file from spring or hibernate annotation

Tags: spring, hibernate, annotations

I want to understand an existing application which has full of annotations. So I do not where to start and how the flow goes afterwards. So is there any tool to generate XML configuration file from spring or  hibernate annotation?

Comment: I am not getting you clearly, are you searching for tool for Hibernate annotation to hmb.xml file conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Answering about hibernate annotation generator. If you want to generate Entities with annotations automatically you can use the JPA Tools from Eclipse. 
First create a DataSource Connection (Choose data source explorer view, right click in database connections. New -> Configure the data base ). Second step, in Eclipse with JPA Tools Package create a JPA Project (New -> JPA Project). Then right click in this project JPA Tools -> Generate Entities From Database, choose connection, Schema and tables, Next, Next (all default values), Next and then finish. After that you will have in the model package  an Entity with annotations about hibernate. you can find more informations in eclipse.org site ( https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/tasks006.htm ) and to create a Database connections (http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.doc.user%2Fdoc%2Fhtml%2Fasc1229700344899.html).